# How to make an IObservable<string> from console input

Tags: c#, console, observable, system.reactive

I have tried to write console observable as in the example below, but it doesn't work. There are some issues with subscriptions. How to solve these issues?

```
static class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // var observable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)).Publish().RefCount(); // works
        // var observable = FromConsole().Publish().RefCount(); // doesn't work
        var observable = FromConsole(); // doesn't work
        observable.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
        await Task.Delay(1500);
        observable.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
        await new TaskCompletionSource().Task;
    }

    static IObservable<string> FromConsole()
    {
        return Observable.Create<string>(async observer =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                observer.OnNext(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If I used `Observable.Interval`, it subscribes two times and I have two outputs for one input. If I used any version of `FromConsole`, I have one subscription and a blocked thread.

Comment: "*but it doesn't work*" <== Could you add a description of the issue in the question?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, yeap! Is it clear now for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To start with, it is usually best to avoid using `Observable.Create` to create observables - it's certainly there for that purpose, but it can create observables that don't behave like you think they should because of their blocking nature. As you've discovered!

Instead, when possible, use the built-in operators to create observables. And that can be done in this case.

My version of `FromConsole` is this:

```
static IObservable<string> FromConsole() =>
    Observable
        .Defer(() =>
            Observable
                .Start(() => Console.ReadLine()))
        .Repeat();
```

`Observable.Start` effectively is like `Task.Run` for observables. It calls `Console.ReadLine()` for us without blocking.

The `Observable.Defer`/`Repeat` pair repeatedly calls `Observable.Start(() => Console.ReadLine())`. Without the `Defer` it would just call `Observable.Start` and repeatedly return the one string forever.

That solves that.

Now, the second issue is that you want to see the value from the `Console.ReadLine()` output by both subscriptions to the `FromConsole()` observable.

Due to the way `Console.ReadLine` works, you are getting values from each subscription, but only one at a time. Try this code:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var observable = FromConsole();
    observable.Select(x => $"1:{x}").Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
    observable.Select(x => $"2:{x}").Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
    await new TaskCompletionSource<int>().Task;
}

static IObservable<string> FromConsole() =>
    Observable
        .Defer(() =>
            Observable
                .Start(() => Console.ReadLine()))
        .Repeat();
```

When I run that I get this kind of output:

```
1:ddfd
2:dfff
1:dfsdfs
2:sdffdfd
1:sdfsdfsdf
```

The reason for this is that each subscription starts up a fresh subscription to `FromConsole`. So you have two calls to `Console.ReadLine()` they effectively queue and each one only gets each alternate input. Hence the alternation between `1` & `2`.

So, to solve this you simply need the `.Publish().RefCount()` operator pair.

Try this:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var observable = FromConsole().Publish().RefCount();
    observable.Select(x => $"1:{x}").Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
    observable.Select(x => $"2:{x}").Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
    await new TaskCompletionSource<int>().Task;
}

static IObservable<string> FromConsole() =>
    Observable
        .Defer(() =>
            Observable
                .Start(() => Console.ReadLine()))
        .Repeat();
```

I now get:

```
1:Hello
2:Hello
1:World
2:World
```

In a nutshell, it's the combination of the non-blocking `FromConsole` observable and the use of `.Publish().RefCount()` that makes this work the way you expect.

Comment: Upvoted. This implementation of the `FromConsole` is indeed better than the `Observable.Create`-based implementation, because it correctly handles unsubscription. Something that is not obvious is that the `Observable.Start` by default invokes the supplied action on the `ThreadPool`, which is a desirable behavior. [In other cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66314910/how-to-make-the-rx-callbacks-run-on-the-threadpool) this is not what happens.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias In what sense does `Observable.Create` not correctly handle unsubscription?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede - The call to `observable.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine)` becomes a blocking call because of the `while (true)` loop.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede if you dispose the subscription to the sequence created by `Observable.Create`, the `while (true)` loop will keep spinning, and it will keep consuming the lines entered in the console. To solve this problem, an overload that accepts a `Func<IObserver, CancellationToken, Task>` lambda can be used instead. The `CancellationToken` is signaled when the subscription is disposed.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - You can't even get to the subscription to dispose it. The call to `Subscribe` is a blocking call thanks to the `while (true)`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Seems to me the problem is `while(true)`, not `Observable.Create`.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede the `while (true)` loop is OK, provided that there is some awaited asynchronous operation inside the loop. The point of my original comment was to compare the `Repeat`-based solution of this answer with the `Observable.Create`-based solution of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67990985/11178549). Both solutions are functionally equivalent, with the exception of their behavior when a subscription is disposed. The `Repeat`-based solution is superior in that aspect, but the `Observable.Create`-based solution can be fixed to match the correct behavior.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede - No, the problem is also the `Observable.Create`. It's a blocking operator on subscription. It should always be used as a last resort. In situations when you only use `Create` to get transient state then `Observable.Defer` is better. Bottom-line avoid `Create` where possible.

Comment: @Enigmativity Hmm. The [Intro to Rx](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#ObservableCreate) book says, "The `Create` factory method is the preferred way to implement custom observable sequences." Obviously there are circumstances where the most natural way to implement the sequence is by blocking, and that's when the blocking subscription becomes a problem. But to say that `Create` should only be used as a last resort seems backwards. It's fine in almost all circumstances.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede - I disagree. I'm one of three people on this site with a gold badge for `system.reactive`. I feel I've got a reasonable handle on it.

Comment: @Enigmativity That makes your viewpoint worth considering, but it still requires justification, especially when it directly contradicts other authoritative sources. More specifically, I acknowledge all the facts you've stated; I just don't think it follows from those facts that `Create` should be avoided. You haven't explained what's wrong with `Create` when the thing being observed is already asynchronous, which IME is by far the most common scenario. (to be continued)

Comment: Does `Defer` ensure that subscribe returns the `IDisposable` subscription before the asynchronous observable potentially emits elements or terminates? Is that the reason to prefer it?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede - `Defer` allows local state for each subscription, which `Create` also does, but it doesn't subscribe to observer in `Defer` so you can use it cleanly with the standard operators.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede - `Create` just encourages coding that introduces deadlocks and race conditions. It's best to avoid for that reason.

Comment: @Enigmativity Sorry, not buying it. Novice developers do novice developer things, and Rx has an exceptionally steep learning curve. That doesn't make `Create` inherently bad. IMO you're throwing out the baby with the bath water because of a rare gotcha that's not even particularly difficult to understand or overcome in the unlikely event you run into it.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede - It occurs each and every time you use the operator. It's just that the content that you put in the `Create` operator, the subsequent operators, or the subscribe can cause this behaviour to manifest itself as a bug. It's often difficult for experienced Rx coders to diagnose, hence why I say it should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Console.ReadLine` is a blocking method, so the subscription to the `FromConsole` sequence blocks indefinitely, so the `await Task.Delay(1500);` line is never reached. You can solve this problem by reading from the console asynchronously, offloading the blocking call to a `ThreadPool` thread:

```
static IObservable<string> FromConsole()
{
    return Observable.Create<string>(async observer =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            observer.OnNext(await Task.Run(() => Console.ReadLine()));
        }
    });
}
```

You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22664392/await-console-readline) question about why there is no better solution than offloading.

As a side note, subscribing to a sequence without providing an `onError` handler [is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47231242/why-isnt-observable-finally-being-called/), unless having the process crash with an unhandled exception is an acceptable behavior for your app. It is especially problematic with sequences produced with `Observable.Create<T>(async`, because it can lead to weird/buggy behavior like this one: [Async Create hanging while publishing observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51714221/async-create-hanging-while-publishing-observable/).

Comment: This is only half the solution. Even with the `await Task.Run(() => Console.ReadLine())` you only get one output yet there are two subscriptions.

Comment: @Enigmativity in my tests I see both subscriptions working (both `onNext` handlers are invoked), provided that I use the commented `FromConsole().Publish().RefCount();` sequence in the OP's example.

Comment: I just retested your code and you're only getting one value out yet you have two subscriptions.

Comment: @Enigmativity [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W8v3M6) is my code, and [here](https://snipboard.io/cymDUs.jpg) is a sample output, after typing the lines 'Hello' and 'World'.

Comment: Your code in the answer doesn't show you are running the `.Publish().RefCount()` observable. You don't show the code and you don't explain it in the answer. I can only assume you're using the OP's code to run the query.

Comment: You also don't explain why the plain version of the observable fails.

Comment: My friend the OP is experimenting in their example with various ways to use the `FromConsole` sequence. It happens that currently the `FromConsole().Publish().RefCount();` is commented and the `FromConsole();` is not, but it could be the other way around. I addressed the main issue in the OP's code, the blocking nature of the `Console.ReadLine` method, and I am assuming that the OP will be able to figure out the rest. Btw even with the current state of the OP's example, both subscriptions are effective, with each one observing half of the lines typed in the console.

Answer (score -1):

You need to return a observable without the publish. You can then subscribe to it and do your thing further. Here is an example. When I run it i can readline multiple times.

```
public class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FromConsole().Subscribe(x =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        });
    }

    static IObservable<string> FromConsole()
    {
        return Observable.Create<string>(async observer =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                observer.OnNext(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Similar issues with this version of observable. Wait for a minute. I will add full example of my test code.

Comment: I have added a full example of my test code. If you run it, you will see the issue.